# inappmessaging-display:17.0.0' CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging, android-studio-3.1.4

When I add 
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.0'` to my gradle file, Android Studio cannot generate apk, instead it gives this error:

> CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long.

[image: Android Studio Detailed Errors]

Any help would be much appreciated guys. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try updating your dependency version to 17.0.1?

Comment: I did update, it works fine, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove these two libraries

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Also, I found it crashes when you are using Picasso library, you might want to downgrade it or remove it all. it is already installed in the inappmessaging library

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Don't forget to change the

`Picasso.get()` to `Picasso.with(getContext)`

Now it builds fine... Though my answer needs more research from you guys...