# my app is crushing after adding in app mesaging

Tags: java, android

i am trying to add firebase inapp messaging but am getting 64k limit error

added multi dex true but it is working and crash when i debug the app

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

i want to my code to be analised and work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code and the full complete error message you get.

Comment: `firebase-inappmessaging-display` only accompanies `firebase-inappmessaging` ...while this one dependency pulls in a lot of duplicate dependencies, which prevent the build. look for an error message, which complains about "program type already exists"... then you can search for that error message by the actual name of the class; and I'm sure it would be a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inappmessaging-display:17.0.0' CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949598/inappmessaging-display17-0-0-createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extensio)